Problem with API when running container Minio and Nginx proxy server
I have a problem with access to the API at sub.domain.com:9000/....
The WebUI is working normally on sub.domain.com.
My docker-compose.yml for Minio:
I have problem with access to api by sub.domain.com:9000/....
WebUI working normaly on sub.domain.com.
My docker-compose.yml for minio:
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    expose:
      - 80
      - 9000
    networks:
      - nginx_default
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=standard
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=sub.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=sub.domain.com
    command: server --address ":9000" --console-address ":80" /data

networks:
  nginx_default:
    external: true

volumes:
  minio_data:

My docker-compose.yml for Nginx reverse proxy:
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: "nginx"
        image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
            - /var/docker/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
            - /var/docker/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
            - /var/docker/nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: "10m"
                max-file: "3"
    letsencrypt-companion:
        container_name: "nginx-le"
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes_from:
            - nginx
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /var/docker/nginx/acme:/etc/acme.sh
        environment:
            DEFAULT_EMAIL: mail@domain.com

What should I change in my configuration so that the API works at the address: sub.domain.com:9000/...?
